# How to get a template tag to auto-check a checkbox in Django

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I'm using a ModelForm class to generate a bunch of checkboxes for a ManyToManyField but I've run into one problem: while the default behaviour automatically checks the appropriate boxes (when I'm editing an object), I can't figure out how to get that information in my own custom templatetag.

Here's what I've got in my model:

```
from myproject.interests.models import Interest


class Node(models.Model):
    interests   = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, blank=True, null=True)


class MyForm(ModelForm):

    from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple, ModelMultipleChoiceField

    interests = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple(), 
        queryset=Interest.objects.all(),
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

And in my view:

```
from myproject.myapp.models import MyModel,MyForm

obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
f   = MyForm(instance=obj)

return render_to_response(
    "path/to/form.html", {
        "form": f,
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

And in my template:

```
{{ form.interests|alignboxes:"CheckOption" }}
```

And here's my templatetag:

```
@register.filter
def alignboxes(boxes, cls):
    """
        Details on how this works can be found here:
            http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/
    """

    r = ""
    i = 0
    for box in boxes.field.choices.queryset:
        r += "<label for=\"id_%s_%d\" class=\"%s\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" id=\"id_%s_%d\" /> %s</label>\n" % (
            boxes.name,
            i,
            cls,
            boxes.name,
            box.id,
            boxes.name,
            i,
            box.name
        )
        i = i + 1

    return mark_safe(r)
```

The thing is, I'm only doing this so I can wrap some simpler markup around these boxes, so if someone knows how to make that happen in an easier way, I'm all ears.  I'd be happy with knowing a way to access whether or not a box should be checked though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the value I was looking for, the elements in the list that were "checked" isn't in the `field`, but rather part of the `form` object.  I re-worked the template tag to look like this and it does exactly what I need:

```
@register.filter
def alignboxes(boxes, cls):

    r = ""
    i = 0
    for box in boxes.field.choices.queryset:
        checked = "checked=checked" if i in boxes.form.initial[boxes.name] else ""
        r += "<label for=\"id_%s_%d\" class=\"%s\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" id=\"id_%s_%d\" %s /> %s</label>\n" % (
            boxes.name,
            i,
            cls,
            boxes.name,
            box.pk,
            boxes.name,
            i,
            checked,
            box.name
        )
        i = i + 1

    return r
```

For those who might come after, note that the `checked` value above was found in `boxes.form.initial[boxes.name]`

Answer (score 3):

In your *input* tag for the checkbox, you can just add the *checked* attribute based on some condition. Say your box object has property *checked* which value is either "checked" or empty string ""

```
r += "<label for=\"id_%s_%d\" class=\"%s\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" id=\"id_%s_%d\" %s /> %s</label>\n" % (
    boxes.name,
    i,
    cls,
    boxes.name,
    box.id,
    boxes.name,
    i,
    box.checked,
    box.name
)
```

Comment: That's the thing, the box object doesn't have a "checked" property.  I'm trying to find out where I can get that value given that all I have to work with is {{ form.interests }}.  I assume that the data must be in there, 'cause if I render it without the template tag, the boxes are checked automatically.